# Creating a new instance of a window I have created. Called multiple times to do different things

Tags: c#, wpf, class, xaml, textbox

I have created a window which is a numbered keypad :

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Name="btnTotal" Width="280" Height="60" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,10,10" Background="#302F37" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" FontSize="35"></TextBox>
    <Button x:Name="btnZzero" Content="0" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5,5,5,5" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White" Focusable="False"  Click="btnZzero_Click"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnOk" Content="OK" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5,5,5,5" Click="btnOk_Click" Background="#FF8FC377" Focusable="False"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5,5,5,5" Click="cancel_Click" BorderBrush="Black" Background="#FFD64D4D" Focusable="False"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnOne" Content="1" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="14,6,0,6" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="btnOne_Click"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnTwo" Content="2" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5,5,5,5" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White" Click="btnTwo_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnThree" Content="3" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5,5,5,5" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnFour" Content="4" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,5,5,5" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnFive" Content="5" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,5,5,5" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnSix" Content="6" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,5,5,5" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnSeven" Content="7" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,5,9,6" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnEight" Content="8" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,5,5,5" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnNine" Content="9" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,5,5,5" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White"></Button>
```

Now, I would like to call this keypad at different times in my application to do different things.

IE I want to use it for a login screen :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainLogin2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     Title="MainLogin2" WindowState="Maximized" Width="1024" Height="768" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid Background="#FF260538">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="768" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1024" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Name="userIDTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="402,249,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="User ID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" FontSize="30" PreviewMouseDown="userIDTextBox_PreviewMouseDown"  />
    <TextBox Name="passcodeTextBox" Height="47" Margin="402,317,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Passcode" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" PreviewMouseDown="passcodeTextBox_PreviewMouseDown" />

    <Button Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,386,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" Height="59" FontSize="30" Click="okButton_Click"/>
    <Button Content="CANCEL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,450,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" Height="59" FontSize="30" Click="cancelButton_Click_1"/>
</Grid>
```

My problem is how do I pass the result from the keypad back to different text fields after I have clicked ok?

Here is the code behind the keypad window. I only have the number 1 working so far for testing:

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{        
    public partial class QuantityKeypad : Window
    {
        bool btnClicked = false;
        string quantityResult = "";         

        public QuantityKeypad()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnZzero_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnOne_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnClicked == true)
            {
                btnTotal.Text = "";
                btnClicked = false;
            }
            quantityResult = quantityResult += "1";
            btnTotal.Text = quantityResult;
        }

        private void btnTwo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }       
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the login screen :

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{    
    public partial class MainLogin2 : Window
    {
        public MainLogin2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        //OK button
        private void okButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.Show();
            this.Close();
        }

        //Cancel button - takes user back to login screen
        private void cancelButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        //Removes text from login textboxes when clicked in
        //opens instance of Quantitykeypad when clicking inside textbox
        private void userIDTextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            userIDTextBox.Text = "";
            QuantityKeypad loginKeypad = new QuantityKeypad();

            loginKeypad.Owner = this;
            loginKeypad.ShowDialog();
        }

        //Removes text from passcode textboxe when clicked in
        //opens instance of Quantitykeypad when clicking inside passcode textbox
        private void passcodeTextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            passcodeTextBox.Text = "";
            QuantityKeypad loginKeypad = new QuantityKeypad();

            loginKeypad.Owner = this;
            loginKeypad.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Terribly sorry if this is simple but I have been struggling for days now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your private field `quantityResult` a publicly accessible property instead:

```
public string QuantityResult { get; private set; }
```

That way, you can read from it:

```
passcodeTextBox.Text = "";
QuantityKeypad loginKeypad = new QuantityKeypad();

loginKeypad.Owner = this;
loginKeypad.ShowDialog();

passcodeTextBox.Text = loginKeypad.QuantityResult;
```

Comment: I cant thank you enough.  
I used :
    public string QuantityResult { get; set; }

Instead, so I can clear the QuantityResult everytime the keypad is called.

Thank you so much.